# How can I troubleshoot high latency between my PC and my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

My internet is provided by my landlord. Up until about a month ago, each apartment had a separate router and internet connection, and it worked fine. Recently, however, my landlord switched to a Comcast "business class(?)" network, and since then, I have been getting periodic spikes of *incredibly high* latency between my computer and the Comcast router.

My computer is attached with an ethernet cable to a router running DD-WRT (with a static IP of 192.168.1.6), which connects in wireless bridge mode to the main Comcast router (192.168.1.1).

About 50%-60% of the time, the latency between my PC and 192.168.1.1 in the single or double digit range and the internet works fine. The rest of the time, the latency jumps up to >10000 ms, stays there for a minute or two, and then drops back down. For example:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14068 ttl=64 time=21836 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14069 ttl=64 time=20847 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14070 ttl=64 time=20789 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14071 ttl=64 time=21856 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14072 ttl=64 time=21521 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14073 ttl=64 time=20515 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14074 ttl=64 time=19540 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14075 ttl=64 time=19271 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14076 ttl=64 time=20779 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14077 ttl=64 time=20974 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14078 ttl=64 time=20058 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14101 ttl=64 time=875 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14102 ttl=64 time=22.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14103 ttl=64 time=17.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14104 ttl=64 time=1435 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14105 ttl=64 time=667 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14106 ttl=64 time=40.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14107 ttl=64 time=201 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14108 ttl=64 time=9.89 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14109 ttl=64 time=2843 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14112 ttl=64 time=2264 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14115 ttl=64 time=1664 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14116 ttl=64 time=810 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14117 ttl=64 time=72.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14118 ttl=64 time=133 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14119 ttl=64 time=11.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14120 ttl=64 time=25.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14121 ttl=64 time=18.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14122 ttl=64 time=152 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14123 ttl=64 time=10.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14124 ttl=64 time=108 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14125 ttl=64 time=17.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14126 ttl=64 time=171 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14127 ttl=64 time=32.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14128 ttl=64 time=706 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14129 ttl=64 time=17.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14130 ttl=64 time=42.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14131 ttl=64 time=30.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14132 ttl=64 time=37.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14133 ttl=64 time=40.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14134 ttl=64 time=33.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14135 ttl=64 time=20.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14136 ttl=64 time=407 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14137 ttl=64 time=23.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14139 ttl=64 time=80.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14140 ttl=64 time=51.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14141 ttl=64 time=15.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14142 ttl=64 time=31.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14143 ttl=64 time=11.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14146 ttl=64 time=878 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14147 ttl=64 time=21.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14148 ttl=64 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14149 ttl=64 time=400 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14150 ttl=64 time=42.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14151 ttl=64 time=1434 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14153 ttl=64 time=805 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14154 ttl=64 time=231 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14155 ttl=64 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14156 ttl=64 time=1206 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14157 ttl=64 time=449 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14158 ttl=64 time=1256 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14159 ttl=64 time=275 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14160 ttl=64 time=977 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14161 ttl=64 time=1220 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14162 ttl=64 time=974 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14163 ttl=64 time=91.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14164 ttl=64 time=1716 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14165 ttl=64 time=2175 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14166 ttl=64 time=3899 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14167 ttl=64 time=4102 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14168 ttl=64 time=3203 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14169 ttl=64 time=2198 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14170 ttl=64 time=2025 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14173 ttl=64 time=1773 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14174 ttl=64 time=772 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14175 ttl=64 time=10.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14176 ttl=64 time=56.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14177 ttl=64 time=1670 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14178 ttl=64 time=689 ms
```

If I also have my laptop connected to the network when these spikes occur (in the same room), then the laptop is affected too.

I suspect that the problem is one of:

1. Physical interference between me and the AP
2. Some kind of clash between my client bridge and the Comcast router
3. Some unrelated issue with the Comcast hardware that I need to report to my landlord (Comcast service was already called a few weeks ago because of complaints in the building about speed).

How can I tell where the problem is?

Comment: Why won't you connect the laptop directly to the Comcast router and check pings?

Comment: @ilkhd The laptop was (I believe) directly connected to the Comcast router. I don't have physical access to the AP. It was connected to the network whose SSID matched the Comcast router, and I don't think (?) that a client bridge works as a repeater.

Comment: Then IMO the answer is 3.